# Localizing Ribbon Custom Action

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, localization

I am localizing a SharePoint Hosted App and successfully applied localization to custom list but localizing following two elements seems to be not working:

1. Ribbon Custom Action
2. Menu Item Custom Action

The problem is that on Ribbon and Custom Action it is shwoing `$Resources:RESOURCENAME` instead of Resource Value. By the way, the custom action is defined as under in my app:

```
<CustomAction 
Id="CUSTOM_ACTON_ID"
RegistrationType="List"
RegistrationId="101"
Location="EditControlBlock"
Sequence="10003"
Title="$Resources:CUSTOM_ACTION_DISPLAYTEXT">
```

Any guess what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit the app package and copied the three relationship tags from **AppManifest.xml.res** to **feature<"guid">.xml.rels** in _rels folder and it resolved the issue. For details check-out this [blog](http://msscorner.de/2013/03/11/how-to-create-a-multilingual-sharepoint-app-using-resources/).

Answer (score 0):

Your SharePoint hosted app solution in VS should have a folder named Resources (Host Web). In this folder you should have a resource file named Resources.en-US.resx with the key and the string. The custom should be able to locate the resource file.

Comment: I already have _Resources (Host Web)_ folder and _Resources.en-US.resx_ file in it with the key and the string (name/value) but still it is not showing correctly.